GitHub Actions Error: Unable to Build Xcode 16 Project Due to Compatibility with Xcode 15.2 Runners
I'm using GitHub Actions to build an iOS project created in Xcode 16, but the runner only has Xcode 15.2, causing build failures with errors about the .xcodeproj file being unreadable. Has anyone found a workaround to run Xcode 16 projects on GitHub Actions, or do I need a self-hosted runner?

Which macOS runner? macos-13 runner has Xcode 15.2 (default). Please add this information in the question. Regarding Xcode 16, can you not install it manually? Maybe, you can use https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-xcode-version to set it up. macos-14-arm64 has Xcode 16 but it's going to be removed.

One solution is to switch your runner to macos-15. For macos-14 the Xcode 16.0 is removed.
See here and here for more.
This is just annoying...
